# Struggling to add line of code to MainApplication.java onCreate() via expo plugin mods

Tags: react-native, expo

I have studied [the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/plugins-and-mods/) for Expo plugin mods and I don't see an easy way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

My application is expo managed so the native android and ios directories are generated at build time. So I can't just add code directly to MainApplication.java like I'd like to. Instead, I need to use expo plugin mods.

I am able to add the import that I need relatively easily via withMainApplication and adding an import. I am also able to add the file that I need added (a config file) for the integration of this SDK that I am trying to add. However, they also require me to add an initialize line to the onCreate override.

This is where I'm stuck.

Here is my plugin file

```
import { ConfigBuilder } from './configBuilder';

const pkg = require('../../package.json');

/**
 * Configures native code, build settings, and app permissions for Streem SDK and its dependencies
 * @param expoConfig
 * @param options
 * @returns config
 **/
const withEmbrace: ConfigPlugin = expoConfig => {
    /*
     * Configuration for setting up Embrace SDK in Android and iOS
     */
    function configureEmbrace(configBuilder: ConfigBuilder) {
        // Android Embrace SDK setup
        const contents = JSON.stringify({
            app_id: '######',
            api_token: '############################',
        });
        configBuilder.addImportEntry('import io.embrace.android.embracesdk.Embrace;');
        configBuilder.addFile('android', 'android/app/src/main/embrace-config.json', contents);
        // iOS Embrace SDK setup
        // const fileContentsIOS = fs.readFileSync('./embrace_config.plist', 'utf8');
        // configBuilder.addFile('ios/embrace_config.plist', fileContentsIOS);
    }

    const configBuilder = new ConfigBuilder(expoConfig);
    configureEmbrace(configBuilder);
    return configBuilder.build();
};

export default withEmbrace;
```

And here is the line I need added to the onCreate override

```
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Embrace.getInstance().start(this, false, Embrace.AppFramework.REACT_NATIVE);
    ...
  }
```

Does anybody know how to add that line to the MainApplication.java's onCreate via a plugin mod? I'm struggling to find it in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

[FULL REWRITE OF ANSWER]

To get your own native code (e.g. Java or Kotlin), then in your Expo Module project you would put the `onCreate()` code you have above into a custom class that you build in the Android project:

```js
package expo.modules.mylib;

import android.app.Application;

import expo.modules.core.interfaces.ApplicationLifecycleListener;

public class MyLibApplicationLifecycleListener implements ApplicationLifecycleListener {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Embrace.getInstance().start(this, false, Embrace.AppFramework.REACT_NATIVE);
    // ...
  }
}
```

where all instances of the substring "mylib" (case preserving) would be the name of your custom module.

You then include your custom module in your full app project.  When the full app is being compiled, the custom Config Plugin gets invoked and the above logic gets injected into the "native app" as part of the build process.

Comment: Heard. I am trying to add a single line to the onCreate of the MainApplication because it's required as part of the integration by a crash reporting SDK that I'm trying to integrate into our expo managed application. I have created a plugin (and pasted the code in my initial question) but am struggling to learn how to utilize mods to have it add the necessary line to onCreate.

Comment: @Greg Fenton How do you call/reference this file? When trying to set this up in an Expo module, compiling fails as it tries to coerce all modules into a Module type, whereas this is an ApplicationLifecycleListener.

Comment: Are you trying to follow: https://docs.expo.dev/modules/config-plugin-and-native-module-tutorial/